# why i didn't get The same result for these two different queries for Get actors who have appeared in at least 5 films

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, unwind

I'd like to retrieve a list of actors who have appeared in a minimum of 5 films using two different queries.
In the first query, $unwind is not used, but within the $group stage, it matches every actor's details. This query aims to collect and count actors without breaking down the actors array.

In the second query, $unwind is utilized to deconstruct the table into separate objects, allowing us to analyze individual actors. While the end goal is to obtain a list of actors(Table of object) who have participated in at least 5 films, the use of $unwind makes the second query slightly different.

**First Request**

```
db.films.aggregate([
  {
        $unwind:'$actors'
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        prenom:'$actors.first_name',
        nom:'$actors.last_name'
      },
      nbr_films: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      nbr_films:{$gte:5}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
        _id:0,
        nom:"$_id.nom",
        nbr_films:1
    }
  }
]);
```

**returns:**

```
[
  {
    "nbr_films": 6,
    "nom": "Willis"
  },
  {
    "nbr_films": 5,
    "nom": "Oldman"
  },
  {
    "nbr_films": 6,
    "nom": "De Niro"
  },
  {
    "nbr_films": 5,
    "nom": "Caine"
  },
  {
    "nbr_films": 6,
    "nom": "Freeman"
  }
]
```

**second request:**

````
  $group: {
    _id: {
      prenom:'$actors.first_name',
      nom:'$actors.last_name'
    },
    nbr_films: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
},
{
  $match: {
    nbr_films:{$gte:5}
  }
},
{
  $project: {
      _id:0,
      nom:"$_id.nom",
      nbr_films:1


  }
}
]); ``` 
**Returns: 
**```
[
{
  "nbr_films": 5
}
]
````

Comment: Can you add the sample documents (ideally in a mongoplayground like that you share)? I suspect that running the aggregations without the trailing `$project` stage will shed some light on what is going on here (specifically the groupings). Pretty sure you'll need to `$unwind` to achieve your desired results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I assume 'actors' is an array because the first query uses '$unwind' on it.

From the rest of query, it would appear that the actors array contains an array of documents like `{first_name:"Bruce",last_name:"Willis"}`.

Without unwinding, `$actors.first_name` will resolve to an array containing all of the `first_name` values from *every* object in the 'actors' array.

For example, if the document looks like:

```
{ "actors": [
  { "first_name": "Bruce", "last_name": "Willis" },
  { "first_name": "Gary", "last_name": "Oldman" },
  { "first_name": "Robert", "last_name": "De Niro" },
  { "first_name": "Michael", "last_name": "Caine" },
  { "first_name": "Morgan", "last_name": "Freeman" }
]}
```

Then `"$actors.first_name"` will resolve to `["Bruce", "Gary", "Robert", "Michael", "Morgan"]` [Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/We5ykonXM03)

When $unwind is used, a new set of documents is created from each input document, each containing a single element from the array.  [Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kJAe3_8wTqU)

In the first query, the actors array was unwound at the start, so the $group's _id contained the first and last name of a single actor, and the count would then be the number of movies that used that actor.

In the second query, actors was not unwound, so the $group's _id contained an array of first_names and an array of last_names for *all* of the actors in that movie.  The count would then be the number of movies that used the same actors, and whose names appeared in the same order in the `actors` array.